# AutoCompleteText Custom adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to set up a Filter for my AutoCompleteTextView that shows suggestions if the typed word matches a word in a HashMap. The problem is that when I try to populate the View in getView() I get the error                                   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException. If i manually give a position in the getView() I get one of the corresponding values from the HashMap, but am unable to select it.

```
 Map<String,List<String>> countries = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

 AutoCompleteAdapter adapter = new AutoCompleteAdapter(this,words);



    MultiAutoCompleteTextView textView = (MultiAutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCountries);
    textView.setThreshold(1);
    textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For the Adapter:

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
List<String>testing = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mContext;
private Map<String,List<String>> mWords;

public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context,Map<String,List<String>> words) {
    mContext = context;
    mWords = words;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mWords.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mWords.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auto_complete_text_view,parent,false);
    }
//Error is caused here by position    
Log.d("Letter", String.valueOf(position));
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    textView.setText(testing.get(position));
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null) {
                List<String> wordList = null;
                if (mWords.containsKey(constraint)) {
                    wordList = new ArrayList<>();
                    wordList.addAll(mWords.get(constraint));
                }


                filterResults.values = wordList;
                filterResults.count = wordList.size();
            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                 if(results !=null && results.count>0){
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                     testing = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
                 }else{
                     notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                 }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
```

}

Comment: May be because testing.size() < mWords.size().

Comment: Just checked and they are both the same size

Comment: After "testing = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;" statment, Check size of  testing & mWords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had the wrong Lists in the getCount() and getItem() methods. It know works perfectly with the HashMap.

Here is the final

```
public class AutoCompleteAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
List<String>testing = new ArrayList<String>();
private Context mContext;
private Map<String,List<String>> mWords;

public AutoCompleteAdapter(Context context,Map<String,List<String>> words) {
    mContext = context;
    mWords = words;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return testing.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return testing.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView =     inflater.inflate(R.layout.auto_complete_text_view,parent,false);
    }

    if(position<testing.size()) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        textView.setText(testing.get(position));
    }
    return convertView;
}


 @Override
 public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint!=null) {
                List<String> wordList = null;
                if (mWords.containsKey(constraint)) {
                    wordList = new ArrayList<>();
                    wordList.addAll(mWords.get(constraint));
                }


                filterResults.values = wordList;
                filterResults.count = wordList.size();

            }
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults  results) {
            if(results !=null && results.count>0){
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                testing = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;

            }else{
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    };
    return filter;
}
}
```